# Get the curl command for each api endpoint defined in swagger.yaml file

Tags: node.js, express, curl, swagger, openapi

I have a swagger.yaml file where I document all the node.js api endpoints. It uses openapi version 3.0.0. We also use express-openapi-validator package to validate the request and response of every api endpoint defined in the yaml file.

I want to get just the curl command for all the endpoints defined the yaml file. Is there any npm package or anything that can help me generate curl command from the swagger.yaml file so that I can display that curl command inside a custom component in react on a custom built page.